# jQuery.noConflict error in google chorme console

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have a big source of mootools&javascripts js file.!

I removed a Jquery js before.

I do not want use IQuery because I do not use it.

Now when check console my site via google I got a JQuery error in line 273:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined mootools.js:273
(anonymous function)
```

Here is a part of js file in line 273:

```
var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();
$K2(document).ready(function () {
    $K2("#comment-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $K2("#formLog").empty().addClass("formLogLoading");
        $K2.ajax({
            url: $K2("#comment-form").attr("action"),
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $K2("#comment-form").serialize(),
            success: function (e) {
                $K2("#formLog").removeClass("formLogLoading").html(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I got error here: `$K2=jQuery.noConflict()`

How can remove this error without using JQuery liberary in my site?

Comment: So why I got this error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort to solve the problem and is about editing an off-site resource.

Comment: edit mootools.js and remove the offending code. clearly the code inside mootools.js is using jquery. (which is just a little bit weird)

Comment: You could convert that jQuery code to MooTools, would be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/svYZk/ - if you post more code maybe we could help you better

Comment: simply load mootools after this line of noconflict code -.-

Answer (score 0):

you get the error because you removed jQuery, so your question really is, who can rewrite my code to mootools instead. since you have demonstrated absolutely no effort in trying to convert it yourself, this question should be closed.

but, the code is nearly like-for-like and it took me 3 mins to rewrite.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    document.id('comment-form').addEvent('submit', function (e) {
        var form = this,
            log = document.id('formLog');

        e.stop();

        log.empty().addClass('formLogLoading');

        new Request.JSON({
            url: this.get("action"),
            method: 'post', // you may have to set content type for RESTful backend
            data: form,
            success: function (e) {
                log.removeClass('formLogLoading').set('html', e.message);
            }
        }).send();
    });
});
```

for future reference, read the manual and the mailing list, conversions have been happening for years in both directions. nobody will do your work for you.